# Retain original document element index of argument passed through sklearn's CountVectorizer() in order to access corresponding part of speech tag

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, stanford-nlp, countvectorizer

I have a data frame with sentences and the respective part of speech tag for each word (Below is an extract of the data I'm working with (data taken from [SNLI](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/) corpus). For each sentence in my collection I would like to extract unigrams and the corresponding pos-tag of that word.

For instance if I've the following:

```
vectorizer_unigram = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words = 'english')

doc = {'sent' : ['Two women are embracing while holding to go packages .'], 'tags' : ['NUM NOUN AUX VERB SCONJ VERB PART VERB NOUN PUNCT']}

sentence = vectorizer_unigram.fit(doc['sent'])
sentence_unigrams = sentence.get_feature_names_out()
```

Then I would get the following unigrams output:

```
array(['embracing', 'holding', 'packages', 'women'], dtype=object)
```

But I don't know how to retain the part of speech tag after this. I tried to do a lookup version with the unigrams, but as they may differ from the words in the sentence (if you for instance do `sentence.split(' ')`) you don't necessarily get the same tokens. Any suggestions of how I can extract unigrams and retain the corresponding part-of-speech tag?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the source code for the `sklearn` [CountVectorizer class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b6/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L892), particularly the [fit function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b6/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1274), I don't believe the class has any way of tracking the original document element indexes relative to the extracted unigram features: where the unigram features do not necessarily have the same tokens. Other than the simple solution provided below, you might have to rely on some other method/library to achieve your desired results. If there is a particular case that fails, I'd suggest adding that to your question as it might help people generate solutions to your problem.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer_unigram = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words = 'english')

doc = {'sent': ['Two women are embracing while holding to go packages .'],
       'tags': ['NUM NOUN AUX VERB SCONJ VERB PART VERB NOUN PUNCT']}

sentence = vectorizer_unigram.fit(doc['sent'])
sentence_unigrams = sentence.get_feature_names_out()

sent_token_list = doc['sent'][0].split()
tags_token_list = doc['tags'][0].split()
sentence_tags = []

for unigram in sentence_unigrams:
    for i in range(len(sent_token_list)):
        if sent_token_list[i] == unigram:
            sentence_tags.append(tags_token_list[i])

print(sentence_unigrams)
# Output: ['embracing' 'holding' 'packages' 'women']
print(sentence_tags)
# Output: ['VERB', 'VERB', 'NOUN', 'NOUN']
```

Comment: Hi Kyle! Thanks for you input. Unfortunately there is not one particular case, as it's a rather large corpus. I will leave the question open for now

Comment: @OLGJ You're welcome. Sure thing, hopefully someone else can come up with something better. I meant if you could add one minimal example where the unigrams do not have the same tokens as the original document -- I believe this might help people potentially solve the issue.